# How do I fix nextjs13 not-found.jsx from auto reloading/refreshing?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Somehow, my app/not-found.jsx is always refreshing every 2 seconds or so, this is my package.json
Is it because it is localhost? Will it stop when I deploy it?

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export": "npm run build && next export -o _static",
    "format": "prettier --check --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "format:fix": "prettier --write --ignore-path .gitignore ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.4",
    "firebase": "^9.22.2",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.16",
    "next": "^13.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^8.27.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.10",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";


export default function NotFound(){
    return (
        <>
        <div>
          testing
        </div>

       </>
        )
};
```

I with different templates as well, with good looking templates but it seems that it doesn't matter but always have the same auto-refreshing error.

Comment: That's expected in dev mode but won't happen with a production build.